# CNContacts -- Address Line 2

Tags: ios, swift, cncontact, cncontactstore

How do we get the address line 2 for a specific contact address. I am able to successfully get the address line 1 using

```
cnContact.postalAddresses.first?.value.street
```

What property do we use to get the address line 2?

Also, how do we prioritize the home address to be displayed rather than the work address? Is this possible?

Comment: The documentation states that multiline street addresses are separated by carriage returns (`\n`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`postalAddresses.first?.value.street` is the full (line 1 and, if present, line 2) of the FIRST postalAddress in an ARRAY of postalAddresses for a Contact (cnContact).  It is not, as you state, "line 1".

Answer (score 2):

If you want to sort the addresses in a particular order, you can do something like:

```
let addresses = contact.postalAddresses.sorted { (address1, address2) -> Bool in
    return self.labelOrder(address1.label) < self.labelOrder(address2.label)
}
```

Where

```
let labelPreferredOrder = [CNLabelHome, CNLabelWork, CNLabelPhoneNumberMobile, CNLabelPhoneNumberiPhone]

private func labelOrder(_ label: String?) -> Int {
    if let label = label, let index = labelPreferredOrder.index(of: label) {
        return index
    }
    return labelPreferredOrder.count + 1
}
```

You might want to add some hard coded label prefixes, too, in case user used their own hard-coded values, or if the contacts may have been imported from third-party source that didn't employ the localized, standard contacts prefixes:

```
let labelPreferredOrder = [CNLabelHome, "Home", "home", CNLabelWork, "Work", "work", CNLabelPhoneNumberMobile, "Mobile", "mobile", "Cell", "cell", CNLabelPhoneNumberiPhone]
```

Bottom line, sort these any way you want. Note, you don't need the phone-related labels for addresses, but you might include them in case you want to sort phone numbers using a similar technique.

---

To get the lines of the street address in an array (where you can fetch line 1 and line 2 separately, `split` it by `\n`:

```
let streetLines = address.value.street.split(separator: "\n")
```

Then a two line street address would be rendered as an array of strings

```
["123 Main Street", "Suite 100"]
```